# How have access to both cls and self in a method

Tags: python

I want to have code that does something like this

```
class myClass:

    def __init__(self):
        self.__var1 = 'var1'
    
    var2 = 'var2'

    def myNormalMethod(self):
        print(self.__var1)

    @classmethod
    def myClassMethod(cls):
       print(cls.__var2)
    
    #How do I do this?
    def myMethod():
        print(self.__var1)
        print(cls.__var2)
```

Right now the final method does not work as I do not know how I can have access to both `self` and `cls`. How do I implement this?

Comment: `myMethod()` should be declared as `myMethod(self)`, so it has access to `self` as a parameter. (Like `myNormalMethod(self)`, above.) You can get `self`'s class using `type(self)`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As a *very* brief review, `self` refers to a current instance of the class while `cls` variables are attached to the class itelf i.e., shared among every instance. Here are some references to help with this, and how I got to your solution:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/25577642/5557662
- [Python datamodel docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html)

I modified your sample code to illustrate the difference and included a solution:

```
class MyClass:
    __var2 = 'var2'
    var3 = 'var3'

    def __init__(self):
        self.__var1 = 'var1'

    def normal_method(self):
        print(self.__var1)

    @classmethod
    def class_method(cls):
       print(cls.__var2)

    def my_method(self):
        print(self.__var1)
        print(self.__var2)
        print(self.__class__.__var2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(MyClass.__dict__['var3'])

    clzz = MyClass()
    clzz.my_method()
```

`__var2` and `var3` are variables saved to the class. You can access any class variable without an instance via `__dict__` which represents the name space.

Since class variables become a part of every instance, you can just call `self` to access them. Alternatively, you can explicitly call `self.__class__.__var2` to make it clear where the intended variable is actually stored.

Comment: Maybe a dumb question, but when I want to access `__var1` inside `class_method`, how do I do that?

Comment: It's worth mentioning that you can access class variables with `self.var`, but not assign them (`self.var = ...` creates an instance variable rather than assigning to the class variable). For that, you *need* `self.__class__.var = ...`).

Comment: @Shahidur You can't. If you find you need to do that, then it probably means your `class_method` should not actually be a `@classmethod`.

Answer (score 13):

You could just do `self.__var2` - any attributes not found on the instance will be automatically looked up in the class.

To make it explicit that you're expecting the attribute to come from the class itself, use `self.__class__.__var2`.

Comment: Does this hold true while setting class attributes too>

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: You can use [Descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors) to achieve this.

While the existing answers work for OP's case, they do not generally solve "How have access to both cls and self in a method".

E.g., here is the definition of two Python classes:

```py
class MyClass:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    # TODO: def foo

class MySubclass(MyClass):
    pass
```

Where I would like to implement `MyClass.foo` such that it exhibits the following behavior for any subclass `MySubclass` of `MyClass`:

```py
MySubclass.foo() == MySubclass.__name__
MySubclass(name="bar").foo() == "bar"
```

If one could pass both `cls` and `self` in the method, this would be easy:

```py
# Does not work because `self` is never set
@classmethod
def foo(cls, self=None):
    if self:
        return self.name
    return cls.__name__
```

In these kind of cases, you can use [Descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors) to build an object that mimics the behavior you want your method to have:

```py
class MyDescriptor:

    def __get__(self, instance, cls):  # instance = self, cls = cls
        if instance is None:
            return lambda: cls.__name__
        else:
            return lambda: instance.name


class MyClass:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    foo = MyDescriptor()
```