# Using class method to access class variable within a class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a question regarding accessing class variable from the class.
Which way is preferred? Why Version 1 works? name isn't instance variable, how it can be accessed using .self?

Version 1:

```
class Base:
    def get_name(self): return self.name

class Child_1(Base):
    name = 'Child 1 name'

child = Child_1()
print(child.get_name())
```

Version 2:

```
class Base:
    @classmethod
    def get_name(cls): return cls.name

class Child_1(Base):
    name = 'Child 1 name'

child = Child_1()
print(child.get_name())
```

Motivation behind this, is defining name once for all instances to save space.

Comment: Version 1 will not always get the class attribute. If there is an instance attribute `name` it will return that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25577642/6045800 TL;DR - *Well, accessing a class attribute through `self` works just fine. __If there is no instance attribute of the same name__, you get the class attribute.
But __assigning to it will hide the class attribute with a new instance attribute of the same name__. Which is probably not what you wanted.*

Comment: Version 1 is typically preferred unless you have a very good reason not to (ie provide more protection against accidentally setting it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.name` by default refers to `cls.name`

if you set it it only sets it for that instance however

```
self.name = "bob"
```

now overrides the class level name

just the same for methods as well

```
class Foo:
    @staticmethod
    def hello():
        print("Hi There From Foo!")
    def __init__(self):
        self.hello() #this works

 Foo.hello() # this also works
 Foo() # print from in the init
```